# Cannot use SELECT SQL statement in NODE,js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to output a list of all the items from a MYSQL table to the console while using Node JS however when trying to use the code it gives me the error thata Callback function is not available with promise clients (the database connection is a promise as it is SSH tunnelled back to our university) any help with this would be really useful!!

```
 var database = require('./dbConfig');
database.then((con) => {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM Pupils', (err, rows) => {
        console.log(rows)
    })
})
```

Comment: Try `con.query('SELECT * FROM Pupils').then(result => console.log(result))`

Comment: Thank you!! This Worked but now it outputs a Column Definition in the console for all columns in the table, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: what is the db library you are using? sequelize?

Comment: `con.query('SELECT * FROM Pupils').then(([result]) => console.log(result))`

Comment: @germanio I guess it's mysql2

Comment: Yeah it is mySQL2

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
await database.promise().query("SELECT * FROM Pupils")
    .then( ([rows,fields]) => {
        //return your results
    })
    .catch(console.log)
```

as a starting point for your code. Then you can tweak it to your needs